# Linux ip route matching the source ip

Tags: linux, ip, route, source

I would like to know if it's possible to tell a Linux kernel to route all packets destinated to X via interface/ip Y but only in case the source IP address would be a specific one.

Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 6):

Yes that's called source routing :

> ip rule add from 10.0.0.10 table toto
>
> ip route add default via 88.88.88.88 dev eth1 table toto

You can have more informations here :

[source routing in the lartc guide](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html)

Answer (score 1):

Any routing decisions based not on destination IP address called PBR (policy-based routing). Usually, PBR is implemented via firewall, so look for possibility to change out interface for packet in iptables.